# Making an updating graph in Python with numpy.float64

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I have made a program that keeps tracks of how much my investments are worth. The type of data I get back from the program is numpy.float64 when I `print(type(Total))`. I can find a lot of tutorials on how to make finantial charts with plotly or matplotlib but none use the numpy.float64 data type. Any idea how I can make a simple live updating graph? I am currently using the following code but it only accepts csv type data if I am correct.

```
class DataShow():
    def Total():
         import plotly.graph_objs as go
         Total = DataCollection.TotalStocksYahoo_fin() + DataCollection.ETHTotal()
         print(Total)    

        fig = go.Figure()

        fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=Total.index,
                     open=Total['Open'],
                     high=Total['High'],
                     low=Total['Low'],
                     close=Total['Close'], name = 'market data'))

        fig.update_layout(
             title='Total Investments',
             xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)

        fig.show()

    def testit(seconds):
        import threading
    
        timer = threading.Event()
        while True:
            print(f"Data refreshes every minute (UTC)")
            timer.wait(seconds)
            DataShow.Total()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DataShow.testit(60)
```

Comment: two points,  you conclusion only works with csv is wrong.  examples work with **pandas** data frame.  one way to get data into a data frame is from a csv, another a **numpy** array. Can you provide reference to library `DataCollection.TotalStocksYahoo_fin()` on pipit or GitHub - it's not obvious when googled... (what's your import?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.